# How to solve for $\theta$ in terms of $a,b,c$ in this expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

[image: profile]

I am trying to design a cam profile like in the above image. There are 2 equations I have come up with that define variable "c". The problem, however, is that variables a, b & c are known values and it is angle $\theta$ that I need to know. The 2 arcs on either end of the straight line are equal. The radius of the arcs and the angle $\theta$ change when any of the variables are changed.

The 2 equations I have so far:

$c = \frac{2a}{\sin \theta}(1-\cos \theta)+\frac{b.\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} $

$c = 2 \left[ \frac{a}{\sin \theta} - \sqrt{ \left( \frac{a}{\sin \theta} \right)^2 - a^2}\, \right] + \frac {b.\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} $

I can't for the life of me manage to rearrange the equation to make $\theta$ the subject!

If anyone is an algebra whiz, any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers.

**EDIT**

Ok, so after a bit of geometric shenanigans, I have come up with some different equations to help solve this but and still struggling to rearrange it. (However, I had to replace $\theta$ with $x$ as I couldn't get $\theta$ to work with the program I drew this with!)

[image: Redrawn Problem]
[image: Single Quadrant]

By drawing a chord for the arc, we can show that the angle of the chord is half that of the slope. What I really need to find is the length of either $e$ or $d$, where $d + e = \frac{c}{2}$

Using the half angle formula I get:

$\tan x = \frac{2 \tan \frac{x}{2} }{1 - \tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}$

Which can be written as:

$\frac{c-2e}{b} = \frac{\frac{2e}{a}}{1-\frac{e^2}{a^2}} $

Simplifying to:

$\frac{c-2e}{b} = \frac{2ae}{a^2-e^2}$

My problem now, is that I can't simplify it to get $e$ on its own!

If anyone has any ideas, that would be awesome!

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): ["Find the radius of two circular arcs in a reverse curve separated by a tangent line"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2781569/409) and [my solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2781844/409). The curve in question is similar, although the parameters describing it differ; there should be a way to translate one to the other, but I don't have time at the moment.

Comment: Your last equation in $e$ write $a^2 c-2 e \left(a^2+a b\right)-c e^2+2 e^3=0$ Still the cubic to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the first equation 
$$c = \frac{2a}{\sin (\theta)}(1-\cos (\theta))+\frac{b\,\sin (\theta)}{\cos (\theta)}$$
using the tangent half-angle substitution, we end with
$$c=\frac{2 t \left(-a t^2+a+b\right)}{1-t^2}$$ that is to say
$$2 a t^3-c t^2-2 t (a+b)+c=0$$ that you can solve using Cardano method.

Probably easier would be Newton method for solving the cubic equation. Starting using $t_0=0$, we should have $t_1=\frac{c}{2 (a+b)}$ and
$$t_2=\frac{c^3 (b-a)+4 c (a+b)^3}{8 (a+b)^4-2 c^2 (a-2 b) (a+b)}$$
$$t_{n+1}=\frac{4 a t_n^3-c t_n^2-c}{2 \left(3 a t_n^2-c t_n-(a+b)\right)}$$

Similarly, if $\theta$ is small, we could expand the first equation as Taylor series
$$c=  (a+b)\theta+\frac{a+4 b}{12} \theta ^3 +\frac{a+16
   b}{120} \theta ^5 +\frac{17  (a+64 b)}{20160}\theta ^7+O\left(\theta ^9\right)$$ and use series reversion to get
$$\theta=\frac{c}{a+b}-\frac{ (a+4 b)}{12 (a+b)^4}c^3+\frac{ \left(a^2+2 a b+16
   b^2\right)}{80 (a+b)^7}c^5+O\left(c^7\right)$$

**Edit**

Still assuming small values fo $\theta$, we could build at $\theta=0$ the $[2,2]$ Padé approximant and get for the whole
$$f(\theta) = \frac{2a}{\sin (\theta)}(1-\cos (\theta))+\frac{b\,\sin (\theta)}{\cos (\theta)}-c$$ the approximation
$$f(\theta)\simeq\frac{-c+  (a+b)\theta+\frac{c  (a+4 b)}{12 (a+b)}\theta ^2}{1-\frac{(a+4 b)}{12 (a+b)} \theta ^2 }$$ Solving the quadratic
$$\theta\simeq \frac{2 \left(\sqrt{3 c^2 (a+4 b) (a+b)+9 (a+b)^4}-3 (a+b)^2\right)}{c (a+4 b)}\tag 1$$ which seems interesting.

Let us try it for $a=1$ and $b=4$. Give $\theta$ a value to compute $c$ and recompute the estimate $\theta_*$ from $(1)$. The table below reproduces results (in degrees).
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\theta & c & \theta_* \\
 5  & 0.43728 & 5.00001 \\
 10 & 0.88029 & 10.0003 \\
 15 & 1.33510 & 15.0020 \\
 20 & 1.80853 & 20.0082 \\
 25 & 2.30862 & 25.0249 \\
 30 & 2.84530 & 30.0617 \\
 35 & 3.43143 & 35.1324 \\
 40 & 4.08434 & 40.2567 \\
 45 & 4.82843 & 45.4605 \\
 50 & 5.69963 & 50.7782 \\
 55 & 6.75373 & 56.2542 \\
 60 & 8.08290 & 61.9466
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Update**

After comments, it is quite sure that we can make better knowing that the area of interest is around $\theta=\frac \pi 4$. To stay "simple", writing the $[1,1]$ Padé approximant, we should get
$$\theta\simeq \frac \pi 4+ \frac{\alpha +\beta c}{\gamma+\delta c}$$ where
$$\alpha=2 \left(\left(6 \sqrt{2}-8\right) a^2+\sqrt{2} a b+b^2\right)$$
$$\beta=2 \left(\sqrt{2}-2\right) a-2 b$$
$$\gamma=2 \left(\sqrt{2}-2\right) a^2+3 \left(5 \sqrt{2}-8\right) a b-2 b^2$$
$$\delta=\left(4-3 \sqrt{2}\right) a-2 b$$ Applied to the case
$$a= \pi 160\frac{12}{360}=\frac{16 \pi }{3}\qquad b= \pi 160\frac{50}{360}=\frac{200 \pi }{9}\qquad c=80$$ this would give
$$\theta\simeq \frac \pi 4 +\frac{90 \left(6 \sqrt{2}-37\right)+\left(337+366 \sqrt{2}\right) \pi }{\left(1161
   \sqrt{2}-2497\right) \pi -90 \left(13+9 \sqrt{2}\right)}\approx 0.761710$$ which converted to degrees would give $43.6427$ while the exact solution would be $\theta=0.7617146$ corresponding to $43.6430$. Not too bad.

Keeping $a=\frac{16 \pi }{3}$ and $b= \frac{200 \pi }{9}$ and varying $c$ over a quite large range, here are some results.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
c & \theta_{approx} & \theta_{exact} \\
 60 & 35.1540 &  35.2569 \\
 65 & 37.4779 &  37.5244 \\
 70 & 39.6591 &  39.6759 \\
 75 & 41.7103 &  41.7142 \\
 80 & 43.6427 &  43.6430 \\
 85 & 45.4666 &  45.4665 \\
 90 & 47.1906 &  47.1894 \\
 95 & 48.8228 &  48.8165 \\
 100 & 50.3704 &  50.3528
\end{array}
\right)$$

**New update**

We could still do much better at the price of a quadratic equation. Around a given angle $\theta_0$, develop the rhs of the original equation as a $[2,2]$ Padé approximant and solve for $\theta$. I shall not give here the formulae but just the results for the last worked case $(\theta_0=\frac \pi 4, a=\frac{16 \pi }{3},  b= \frac{200 \pi }{9})$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 c & \theta_{approx} & \theta_{exact} \\
 60 & 35.256535 &  35.256856 \\
 65 & 37.524331 &  37.524418 \\
 70 & 39.675901 &  39.675917 \\
 75 & 41.714232 &  41.714233 \\
 80 & 43.643029 &  43.643029 \\
 85 & 45.466540 &  45.466540 \\
 90 & 47.189400 &  47.189400 \\
 95 & 48.816481 &  48.816478 \\
 100 & 50.352781 &  50.352763
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: That is helpful as I'm looking to have an angle between 40 and 50 degrees and the margin of error is small.

Comment: @TrolleyTrev. I thought it could be useful. I could elaborate a much better approximation if you give me the range you really want to explore.

Comment: Ideally:
$$a = \pi160\frac{12}{360}$$
$$b = \pi160\frac{50}{360}$$
$$c = 80$$

By trial and error, $\theta$ is very close to 43.64303$^\circ$

Comment: @TrolleyTrev. You must keep in mind that we could do much better but at the price of much more nasty expressions.

Comment: @TrolleyTrev. For the specific values of $(a,b)$ you gave and $60 \leq c \leq 100$, a very good empirical model would be $$\theta=-\frac{18592}{2245}+\frac{2153 \sqrt{c}}{1567}+\frac{862 c}{969}-\frac{88
   c\sqrt{c}}{1997}$$ leading to errors smaller than $0.002$ degrees.

Answer (score 1):

I think one may simplify the problem a lot by realizing that due to symmetry the straight line segment is passing right through the center of your drawing, i.e. given the lower right corner corresponds to $(0,0)$, through $(a+\tfrac{b}{2},\tfrac{c}{2})$. Then it's easy to see that $\tan(\tfrac{\pi}{2}-\theta) = \frac{a+\tfrac{b}{2}}{\tfrac{c}{2}}$. However, the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ are not independent. Infact all you need is $c$ and $2a+b = 2(a+\tfrac{b}{2})$, the latter of which is the width of the rectangle.

Comment: That is somewhat helpful, but main problem I'm facing is that in order to figure out the height component of the arc segments, a trig function is required which means I end up with too many trig functions to simplify down to just one.

Basically, c = 2 * height of arcs + height of slope.